# Decent RSS feed generator for PHP

Tags: php, rss

I need an RSS Feed generator; should I use a class or should I generate the feed myself?

If I should generate it myself, where is a good place to get comprehensive specs of the standards?

If not, are there any good classes out there to do it and do it quickly and do it well?

Comment: I just created a RSS Writer class which is a simple map to rss specification: https://github.com/lingtalfi/RssUtil/tree/master/RssWriter

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[PHP Universal Feed Generator (supports RSS 1.0, RSS 2.0 and ATOM)](https://github.com/mibe/FeedWriter)

> Features:
>
> - Generates RSS 1.0, RSS 2.0 and ATOM 1.0 feeds
> - All feeds are are validated by feed validator.
> - Supports all possible feed elements.
> - Simple and easy to define channel and feed items
> - Implements appropriate namespaces for different versions.
> - Automatically converts date formats.
> - Generates UUID for ATOM feeds.
> - Enables usage of subtags and attributes. (example: image and encloser tags)
> - Completely Object oriented in PHP5 class structure.
> - Handles CDATA encoding for required tags.
> - Nearly same code for generating all kinds of feed

[Examples](https://github.com/mibe/FeedWriter/tree/master/examples)

Comment: @Perter Lind: Set Image adding source to image tag but title and link is not added to the image tag.. urgent please reply soon..

Comment: public function setImage($title, $link, $url)

Comment: Its not setting the link.. It show's only the image without link in that

Comment: Well you can always trace the source to se what's going on. I didn't write it myself. What's the generated markup för the given element?

Comment: Also, check this out http://www.w3schools.com/rss/rss_tag_image.asp

Comment: Great lib but site is always down due to exceeding bandwidth quota limit :)

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot instantiate abstract class FeedWriter. AND generateFeed is spelt wrong!

Comment: @indiekiduk well yeah, they obviously fixed that in later versions of the lib. But this example was written a while back. Take a look at https://github.com/ajaxray/FeedWriter/blob/7dde9536fc9066c96fb44373379a06caea0af1cf/FeedWriter.php#L82 and you'll see that it was spelt wrong in the lib. Also the class wasn't abstract back then. I'm not going to change the example as the question is closed.

Comment: Quick update to this. The `genearateFeed()` is misspelt, it should be `generateFeed()`. Also don't include `FeedWriter.php`, use `FeedTypes.php` instead. Then instantiate with either `new RSS1FeedWriter()`, `new RSS2FeedWriter()` or `new ATOMFeedWriter()`.The library is great and got me setup in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 4):

There will soon be a component for [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) called Zend_Feed_Writer that looks pretty interesting. Here's an excerpt from a feed of one of (perhaps the?) developer of that component, Padráic Brady ([link to the blog post](http://blog.astrumfutura.com/archives/428-New-Zend_Feed_Writer-Component-And-Zend_Feed_Reader-Enhancements-ZF-1.10.html)). He says that it's currently in the Zend Framework Incubator, but that a first official version should be ready by the end of the weekend:

> **Zend_Feed_Writer**
>
> The new kid on the block, to be added
>   in Zend Framework 1.10, is
>   Zend_Feed_Writer. A bit like the older
>   Zend_Feed_Builder classes, its purpose
>   is to generate Atom 1.0 and RSS 2.0
>   feeds. The difference is that, like
>   its sibling Zend_Feed_Reader, it is
>   standards aware and operates entirely
>   using PHP's DOM.
>
> Why another feed generation component?
>   The problem is somewhat similar to the
>   one that Zend_Feed_Reader solved.
>   Generating an RSS and Atom feed is far
>   more involved than sticking a bunch of
>   elements together - each standard has
>   its quirks, its unique features, and
>   its own set of best practices outside
>   of the standards. Using
>   Zend_Feed_Builder, you relied on two
>   things - repetition and validation.
>   Moving away from its core focus
>   required more work, even to the extent
>   of subclassing, and you were always at
>   the mercy of misinterpreting a
>   standard.
>
> Zend_Feed_Writer builds on the simple
>   API of Zend_Feed_Reader (using setters
>   rather than getters) and the concept
>   of having the component understand the
>   standards (so you don't have to). The
>   component is split across two class
>   types - a base data container to store
>   feed data and ensure it conforms to
>   expected formats, and a renderer to
>   actually generate the feeds and
>   provide feedback on standards
>   adherence. For example, in Atom 1.0
>   the omission of a title will generate
>   an exception - a title is an
>   obligatory element under the Atom 1.0
>   standard. While this could be
>   interpreted as a nuisance, the fact is
>   that an invalid Atom 1.0 feed is worse
>   than useless. Better you are irritated
>   now, than later when an online
>   validator calls you rude names :-).
>
> The net result of this approach is
>   that you focus on the data, and let
>   Zend_Feed_Writer worry about what
>   elements and attributes to use. It
>   should, in theory (always a grand
>   thing), be impossible for
>   Zend_Feed_Writer to produce an invalid
>   feed.
>
> Of course, we also throw in the
>   concept of Extensions, as with
>   Zend_Feed_Reader, allowing you to add
>   support for RSS and Atom extensions
>   more dynamically without the need for
>   subclassing or API arm twisting.
>
> If you go looking for
>   Zend_Feed_Writer, it's currently in
>   chunks in the Incubator. I should have
>   it entirely integrated and functional
>   over the weekend. You can however give
>   it a shot for writing Atom 1.0 feeds
>   so long as you stick to the core
>   elements (i.e. most blog feeds). RSS
>   2.0 support is the last piece I need to complete in full.

Comment: Zend_Feed_Writer does exist now: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.writer.html

Comment: Set Image adding source to image tag but title and link is not added to the image tag.. urgent please reply soon..

Answer (score 2):

This page has a decent generator meeting 1.0/2.0/ATOM spec so you could either use it (PHP5) or just get a general idea of what is needed:

[Php FeedWriter](http://phpfeedwriter.webmasterhub.net/)

The usage notes at the bottom are fairly detailed and you don't even have to download to view source.

Comment: Hi cballou, your link isn't working...

Comment: @Antony - fixed the link. not quite sure what happened earlier but I had just woken up :)

Comment: Set Image adding source to image tag but title and link is not added to the image tag.. urgent please reply soon..

Comment: Your website returns : DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN ...